# Book recommendation for how classical mechanics emerges from quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, quantum-measurements

### Question

So I read this interesting [link](https://blog.jessriedel.com/2015/03/24/how-to-think-about-quantum-mechanics-part-4-quantum-indeterminism-as-an-anomaly/):

> The most glaring problem is that the state spaces of classical and
> quantum mechanics are completely different, so you can’t have a simple
> limiting procedure unless you describe how you’re going to map one
> onto the other

and was wondering if there was any book which was dedicated to this foundational problem on how classical mechanics emerges from quantum mechanics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before hitting the books, you might do your due diligence and review the basic Wikipedia articles, to understand the trail-map. You need to learn the language first, as an awful lot of nonsense has been lavished on the subject.

- [The correspondence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_principle).
- The [map Jess starts from, mapping Hilbert space to phase space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Weyl_transform).
- [QM in phase space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-space_formulation).
- [The density matrix in phase space, called the Wigner function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution).

You may then see any of a number of books.

- If you are not mathematically adept and need to actually *see* the last bit of every formula to get it, try [W Schleich, *Quantum Optics in Phase Space*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/352729435X). The price you pay is, if you are not organized, you get distracted by inessentials (the major problem of questioners on this site, I fear).
- If you already have had a decent mathematical QM course, and can find your way given the map, try [ours](http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/8870). A free [update](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/aaa.pdf) steers you to the answers eschewing excessive thickets of formulas which cloy and disorient some.

There are also fine books by Ulf Leonhardt, Leon Cohen, M W  Wong, etc, but they won't take you by the hand to bring you to the classical limit.

Added as per request on Decoherence:

- [P Schwaha et al., J Comput Electron 12 (2013) 388-396](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257578554_Decoherence_Effects_in_the_Wigner_Function_Formalism), [or](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10825-013-0480-9); [P Kazemi, S Chaturvedi, I Marzoli, R O’Connell, and W Schleich, New J Phys 15 (2013) 013052](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/15/1/013052/meta); even [C C Meaney, R McKenzie, and G Milburn, Phys Rev E83 (2011) 056202](https://journals.aps.org/pre/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevE.83.056202?casa_token=3Gk1jK7Z140AAAAA%3AG15eOxlFV30-se7nqD8Co65IhhSTOwIjHrgGbUbsW6dNiXJ4NCjaL0t-hfr5eoiu47fDFMtiW2AMFw).
- Book: [Schlosshauer, Maximilian (2007). *Decoherence: and the quantum-to-classical transition*. Springer Science & Business Media](http://ndl.ethernet.edu.et/bitstream/123456789/64948/1/336.pdf).

Comment: I was reading W Schleich, Quantum Optics in Phase Space. It doesn't seem to explain decoherence. Can you add a supplementary text of that as well?